# Как выделить столбец из файла .prn в python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Всем здравствуйте, имеется файл .prn следующего вида:

```
filename='D:/EXP/7head+2cup 60kHz/k=15 I=80 mA 20 kg/1p.prn'
with open (filename) as f:
    infile = f.read()
print(infile)
```

[image: Результат чтения файла .prn]

Подскажите как решить следующую задачу: создать переменные, например, "a", "b", "c" которые будут соответствовать данным в столбцах, например: a = [156, 156, 156, 156, 156];
b = [175.50, 175.50, 175.50, 175.50, 175.50]
и так далее. Хочу затем работать с данными списками, применять различные математические операции, например, нахождение среднего, или построение графика a от b. 
Всем заранее спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этих целей существует библиотека Pandas. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/
Пример работы с Вашим файлом.Предполагаю, разделитель знак табуляции.

```
import pandas as pd
filename='test.prn'
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t')
a = list(df['in Buffer']) 
print(a) #Результатом будет список из значений столбца 'in Buffer', как Вы хотели.
```

Но функционал pandas позволяет считать всякое разное своими собственными методами (см. документацию по ссылке).

Comment: Понял, спасибо! Буду изучать.

Answer (score 0):

Кроме библиотеки pandas можно использовать также модуль csv, хотя возможно он не так эстетичен.

```
import csv
with open(filename) as f:
    reader=csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    header_row=next(reader)

    for index, column_header in enumerate(header_row):
        print(index, column_header)    
    temps=[]
    for row in reader:
        temp=float(row[5])
        temps.append(temp)
    print(temps)
0 Sample in Buffer
1 Sample in Window
2 Encouder
3 Resistance
4 Sensor
5 Temp
[304.535, 304.535, 304.535, 304.535, 304.535, 304.535]
```